# Creating a plugin to show a pop-up banner on every page

Tags: plugins

In August, GDPR requires all websites to have a cookie notification on every page. I am creating a custom post type plugin - but I'm having one problem. The content from the custom post type page isn't being pulled in - it's pulling in the content from the page it is on. If I click on the permalink of the notice page - the content displays exactly as I want it. My guess is, because the plugin is on every page "the_content();" pull in the content from the page they are on. I need to know how to work around this.

Here is the code.

THE PLUGIN CODE:

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name: GDPR Cookie Notice
* Description: Adds a Pop-up notice bar on the bottom of the page for GDPR notifications
**/

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'You Shall Not Pass!' );

function gdpr_create_post_type(){
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'GDPR Notice', // => seperator for associative array key => value
        'singular_name'      => 'GDPR Notice',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New GDPR Notice',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit GDPR Notice',
        'new_item'           => 'New GDPR Notice',
        'view_item'          => 'View GDPR Notices',
        'search_items'       => 'Search GDPR Notices',
        'not_found'          => 'No GDPR Notices Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No GDPR Notices Found in Trash'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'has_archive'        => false, // these will be used in pages
        'public'             => true,
        'hierarchical'       => true, // behave like a page
        'rewrite'            => array(
            'with_front'     => false,
            'slug'           => 'gdpr-notice'
        ),
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-id-alt',
        'supports'           => array(
            'title',
            'author',
            'editor',
            'custom-fields',
            'page-attributes'
        )
    );
    register_post_type('gdpr', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'gdpr_create_post_type');
```

?>

THE HEADER.PHP FILE WHERE THE SINGLE PAGE TEMPLATE IS PULLED IN:

```
<header>
    ... main navigation code ...
</header>

<?php get_template_part('single', 'gdpr'); ?>
```

THE SINGLE-GDPR.PHP FILE:

```
<?php 
/* 
The file for the GDPR Cookie Notice post type, registered via a plugin
*/
?>
<div class="cookie-bar">
    <section class="section float-me me-floated">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">

                <!-- I've added both editor and custom field filters to see if I can get even one to work -->

                <?php if ( have_posts()) :
                    while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                        the_content();

                    endwhile; 
                endif; ?>

                <?php if ( have_posts()) :
                    while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'notice', true);

                    endwhile; 
                endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

WP ADMIN - GDPR Notice custom post type page

I'm trying two options – just to see if I can get one to work

WP Editor:
Read our privacy policy to learn more about how we use cookies.

Custom Field:
Name: notice
Value: Read our privacy policy to learn more about how we use cookies.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make a call to the MySQL database and pull that information in the single-gdpr.php template, so replace the WordPress loop with a database call.

```
<?php

    $table_prefix  = '###_';
    $startat = 'englishnotice'; // English Custom Field Name
    $sitepostmeta = $table_prefix . 'postmeta';

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $sitepostmeta WHERE meta_key = '$startat'");

    echo $posts[0]->meta_value;

?>
```

Comment: ERP...

$posts I think is a reserved variable so use $gdprposts - otherwise your blog page and any other custom post type page won't pull in content.

    `$gdprposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $sitepostmeta WHERE meta_key = '$startat'");

    echo $gdprposts[0]->meta_value;`

Answer (score 0):

I used some javascript code to pop up the message, and placed it in my "Simple GDPR' plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-gdpr/ .

I got the javascript code from https://cookieconsent.insites.com/ , which details how to do it.

I used  the 'after_header' action , as in

```
add_action('after_header', 'my_gdpr_notice');
```

to display the notice, plus using the '`enqueue_scripts`' functions to add the javascript code and the associated CSS for the message.

Comment: Rick. I decided to replace the SINGLE-GDPR.PHP FILE Wordpress loop by querying the database table in mysql and spitting that out. Do you think that is a good idea or not?

Comment: Not sure why you have to put your GDPR notice in a post, then query for the post for every page load. My plugin just adds some javascript and stuff to the page; that displays the popup notice. Clicking the notice sets a cookie. if cookie set, no more notice (for a year). And the popup references the Privacy page with a link (the plugin lets you choose a page to be the 'privacy page'). Using a plugin to display the notice saves a query to the database: if the cookie is set, there is no need to display the notice. If no cookie, display the notice. Simple, in my mind. Works easy. Look at my code.

Comment: I wrote a blog entry about how I did it: https://securitydawg.com/gdpr-and-analytics-and-compliance/ ; basic code that is added to via the wp-head filter. The plugin does a bunch more, but the code in the blog is a start.

Comment: This is my first plugin so I'm experiencing a bit of a learning curve while developing it. I looked at your plugin and didn't see WPML support - which I need for a multilingual mutlisite. There are plugins that we can purchase licenses for that will cover WPML - but where's the fun in "not" learning how to create a plugin?... Your plugin looks very easy to use, though.

Comment: Yeah, no multilanguage support in my plugin. I supposed I could add it, but not sure it's worth the effort. I mostly developed it for my own purposes - didn't find a GDPR plugin that I liked; some were too complex, others wanted $. All I needed is a simple popup message, since my sites are US-based. So, built my own...and had 'fun' developing it.